# Global variable in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, global-variables

Is it possible to access a variable throughout the application with out creating static or session or cookie variable in Silverlight?

I know you can create session in WCF and access it. But I want to know is there any other way?

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you need this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Global variables in Silverlight can be the following:

1. Static variable stored in Class Library that all libraries reference **(Client Side)**
2. Write a cookie **(Client Side)** [Demo](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/15/tip-of-the-day-18-how-to-set-browser-cookies.aspx)
3. If HTML5 based then you can write to SessionStorage or LocalStorage **(Client Side)** [Demo](http://html5demos.com/storage)
4. A WCF service connecting to a client with the variable **(Server Side)**
5. A SQL database (Linq -> SQL) contain he variable **(Server Side)** [Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-UIjQsEiL4)